# How to get the message using message id in Mailkit?

Tags: c#, .net, mailkit

I am using mail kit to send receive mail, and manage all records in my database. I am storing all user action for particular mail and then execute it using my code.
I am storing message id in the table for the unique message, now I want to get the message using messageid. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, don't expect the Message-Id header to be globally unique. Any hacker could easily create their own message and re-use a known Message-Id to try and confuse software that depends on Message-Ids being unique.

That said, you'll need to use the `IMailFolder.Search()` API combined with `SearchQuery.HeaderContains()` to search for messages with a particular Message-Id header.

```
var uids = folder.Search (SearchQuery.HeaderContains ("Message-Id", "blah@blah.com"));
```